Is a java boolean thread safe if you synchronize the writes only
Is a class with synchronized writes on an instance variable boolean thread safe? E.g.:
boolean foo = true;

public synchronized void setFoo(boolean foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
}

public boolean getFoo() {
  return foo;
}


Have you considered AtomicBoolean to remove all doubt?

Yes, I was actually just looking at the implementation of AtomicBoolean to see if I could get the answer that way. Looks like the getter/setter have no locking mechanism. Just the value is volatile.  I am asking about this specific scenario, because I need to modify some existing code in a class that is already largely synchronized and was wondering if it was an option to just remove the synchronize from the getter.

Basically, no this doesn't work.  If you don't care about memory reads, then the synchronization you have does nothing.  And if you do care, then you must synchronize both.  The compiler must know that it can't optimize that read into a register or similar, the value must be re-read.

No, not thread-safe.
You’ve not considered the problem of visibility.
Changes to the primitive boolean are not necessarily visible across threads. Because of the ways modern CPUs work, optimizations made by the JIT compiler, and the Java Memory Model,  one thread may not see the changes made by another thread.
volatile
One way to solve the visibility problem is to mark the primitive boolean  variable as volatile.
AtomicBoolean
Another way is to replace your AtomicBoolean object instead of the primitive boolean. Mark the AtomicBoolean variable as final to guard against inadvertently assigning another instance.
final AtomicBoolean atomicFoo = new AtomicBoolean ( true ) ;

Then use the getter/setter methods to access and manipulate the boolean payload kept within that object in a thread-safe manner.
Personally, I prefer the Atomic… classes. Using these classes means the programmer must call methods rather than merely make assignments. This phenomenon is a constant reminder to the programmer that they are operating in a multi-threaded situation.
Regarding existing code, the compiler will be an enormous help in refactoring to use AtomicBoolean. Every place that primitive was accessed or manipulated will be highlighted as a compiler error requiring your attention.

The accepted answer is insightful and correct in explaining the visibility issues with the volatile keyword and the benefits of using AtomicBoolean. However, it's essential to clarify that while volatile ensures visibility, it does not guarantee atomicity for compound operations. This distinction is crucial to avoid misunderstandings, especially for beginners.
Visibility vs. Atomicity
volatile
The volatile keyword ensures that any read or write to a variable is immediately visible to all threads. However, it does not provide atomicity for compound actions, such as check-then-act operations or increments.
public class MyClass {
    private volatile int foo = 1;

    public synchronized void setFoo(int foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void incrementFoo() {
        foo++; // Not atomic, may cause race conditions
    }
}

In the example above, the incrementFoo() method is not atomic. Multiple threads calling incrementFoo simultaneously can cause race conditions, leading to incorrect results.
AtomicInteger
The AtomicInteger class provides atomic operations and ensures both visibility and atomicity. This makes it suitable for scenarios where you need to perform compound actions safely in a concurrent environment.
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyClass {
    private final AtomicInteger atomicFoo = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public void setFoo(int foo) {
        atomicFoo.set(foo);
    }

    public int getFoo() {
        return atomicFoo.get();
    }

    public void incrementFoo() {
        atomicFoo.incrementAndGet(); // Atomic operation
    }
}

In the incrementFoo method above, incrementAndGet ensures that the operation is atomic, preventing race conditions.
Summary

volatile: Ensures visibility but does not guarantee atomicity. Use it for simple flag updates or single read/write operations where atomicity is not required.
AtomicInteger: Ensures both visibility and atomicity, making it suitable for more complex operations where thread safety is crucial.
By explaining the difference between visibility and atomicity and providing examples with AtomicInteger, it's clearer why atomic classes might be preferable in certain situations and how volatile has its limitations. This additional context should help beginners understand when to use each approach.

